# How to vertical center a TikZ node within a text line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  Text \tikz\filldraw [lightgray,radius = 1pt] (0,0) circle[anchor = north]; more Text \tikz\filldraw [black,radius = 1pt] (0,0) circle[anchor = north]; more Text.
\end{document}
```

produces the following result

[image: result]

As you can see the circles are on the baseline of the text line.

How can one vertically center the circles within the text line? Vertically center is meant if one would draw a virtual line through the vertical center of the small letters, excluded letters with ''non standard'' height: f,g,h,i,j,k,l,p,q,t,y.

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "centered"... with respect to the "t" or the "m"? (or the base line skip, or...)

Comment: Hello @Rmano. Thank you for your comment! See the edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enclose the tikzpicture in `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to avoid manual adjustments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  Text $\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz\filldraw [lightgray,radius = 1pt] (0,0) circle[anchor = north];}}$ more 
  Text $\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz\filldraw [black,radius = 1pt] (0,0) circle[anchor = north];}}$ more Text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one possible way using `y = 0.5ex` which scales with different fonts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \noindent Text \tikz[baseline]\filldraw [lightgray,radius = 1pt] (0,0.5ex) circle;
  more Text \tikz[baseline]\filldraw [black,radius = 1pt] (0,0.5ex) circle;
  more Text.
\end{document}
```

---

You could even create a command to simplify things further in-text:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MidDot}{O{black} O{1}}{%
  \tikz[baseline]\filldraw [#1, radius=#2pt] (0,0.5ex) circle;%
  }

\begin{document}
  \noindent Text \tikz[baseline]\filldraw [lightgray,radius = 1pt] (0,0.5ex) circle;
  more Text \tikz[baseline]\filldraw [black,radius = 1pt] (0,0.5ex) circle;
  more Text.\\
  Text \MidDot[lightgray]
  more Text \MidDot\
  more Text.
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Instead of `0.1`, you can try `.5ex`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit indeed, looks much better and also allows scaling of the fonts, I didn't know `ex` or `em` could go in the coordinates, thank you for that!

Comment: I wouldn't say that `0.5ex` is _hard coded_ as it will adjust with the fontsize so it is exactly what is asked for.